# Strange issue with website URL

Tags: php

I don't even know where to put this issue, my host is not replying to live chat or emails, i have uploaded a file to my server called: links-pending-renewal.php when i type in: http://www.example.org/links-pending-renewal.php it says 404 even though the file is definately there, what i did notice was this: [http://imgur.com/POQz0Ug](https://imgur.com/POQz0Ug)

It says "The requested URL /â€Œlinks-pending-renewal.php was not found on this server." i do not know what this "â€Œ" is, it's not in the filename, i assume this is the issue, on all 3 browsers it shows "404".

I'm totally stumped, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The file name has a "hidden" or invalid character in it that's causing this problem? Or possibly something in your rewrite rules may be adding this?

Comment: Hi Cale, thats the strange thing, i don't have an .htaccess file for this site, and the filename is in the directory with the others just fine, the person who did some work on the file was from China, there is no chinese character sin the comments/code he just did some work and sent, this is the only thing out the norm from usual, very strange!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you might have typed an illegal character in your browser when entering the url.  "â€Œ" suggests that this character is a 7-byte character (a distinct possibility for UTF-8 chars):
EDIT: 7-byte *string*, not 7-byte *char*.

```
$str = "â€Œ";

for($i=0; $i<strlen($str); $i++) {
    $chr = $str[$i];
    echo ord($chr) . "=" . $chr . "\n";
}
```

The output:

```
195=
162=�
226=
130=�
172=�
197=
146=�
```

I don't think the issue is with the filename because if you type in a url and it doesn't match the filename, the resulting 404 message will contain the file you requested, not the name of the file that is actually on the server.  E.g., if the file is named **foo.php** and I request **bar.php**, the server message will complain about **bar.php**.

EDIT: another thought. This could also be due to a url-rewriting rule of some kind.